# Linux Ubuntu Kernel crash: python: Corrupted page table

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, python, kernel-panic

My system configuration:

- Processor: 12th gen Core i7 12700K x 20
- 16 GB RAM
- Not installed external GPU (No Graphics Card). All the GPU is from the processor itself (on chip)
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B760M DS3H AX
- Ubuntu version: 20.04.2 LTS
- Running python version 3.8

I am running machine learning  python code on my ubuntu desktop computer. Sometimes the python code runs smoothly but sometimes it halts (pauses) with the following kernel crash/ kernel panic:

**How do I solve below error ? So, that my python code runs without any problem ?**

Linux Ubuntu Kernel crash: python: Corrupted page table at address 4453d6d8. See image below:

[image]

**How do I solve the above error ? So, that my python code runs without any problem ?**

Comment: Does the kernel keep enjoying messages afterwards on what I guess is your serial console?

Comment: If this computer has no GPU, why is i915 loaded? That's an Intel GPU driver!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you can ignore the "No GPU" part. The board support a CPU iGPU and the CPU has an on chip gpu. I think the op is just a bit confused with that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller.   The CPU has an on chip GPU. I meant to say that I have not installed external GPU (No Graphics Card). All the GPU is  from the processor itself (on chip.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller,  The logs are from the tty console ( from Ubuntu Ctrl + alt + F1 ). Once the kernel crash log appears after that my python code stops (pauses). This kernel crash lag only appears once - not again and again. But then again some different kernel crash log starts appearing again and again.

Comment: @SyedWaris ah! Got you, thanks!

Comment: It's a hardware bug, replace RAM, if that doesn't help, replace CPU, if that doesn't help, replace mainboard. Next time use ECC memory. PS you may also check the memory first for bad addresses and black list these addresses in GRUB configuration

Comment: @paladin Neither the board nor the cpu support & operate ECC. You are asking the op to completely replace their system for a stupid amount of money.

Comment: @Bib whoever is using a system with more than 8GiB of RAM for professional things and without ECC is doing stupid things in the first place, as you can see in OP posted problem. Intel just sucks, for disabling ECC in consumer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop version.
After reinstalling OS to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop issues were not observed anymore. Python version installed to OS's were the same 3.10.
Changing BIOS settings for the "Intel VID" function to the Disabled state fixed the issue in my case. Enter Bios ---> Advanced ---> Intel VID ---> Disable, in case of Acer laptops